# How do I create a custom font for a blackberry application

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, fonts

I want to use a specific foreign language font for a Blackberry application.  How is such a font created and loaded onto the Blackberry device?

For example: ਪੰਜਾਬੀ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search shows that the same thing has been asked at [blackberry forums](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/100107-using-custom-fonts.html).

The solution they came up with is a class for loading the font from a [fnt file](http://www.fileinfo.net/extension/fnt).

There are [programs available](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=free+.fnt+editor&btnG=Search) to import and edit fnt files.

Answer (score 2):

for Blackberry OS 5 or above, you can use class [FontFamily](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Load_and_use_a_custom_font_899948_11.jsp) to load your custom font into application.