# Blackberry - set position of field on the screen?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, layout

I want to position my field at specified positions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

basically to set **any** field position amoung the manager, you shoud:

1. override [sublayout](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#sublayout(int,%20int))

   - set [layoutChild](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#layoutChild(net.rim.device.api.ui.Field,%20int,%20int)) **for each** field in manager
   - set [setPositionChild](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#setPositionChild(net.rim.device.api.ui.Field,%20int,%20int)) **for each** field in manager
   - use [setExtend](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setExtent(int,%20int)) to size manager properly

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Code of extanded manager:

```
class CustomVerticalManager extends VerticalFieldManager {
 LabelField mText1 = new LabelField("top");
 LabelField mText2 = new LabelField("bottom");

 public CustomVerticalManager() {
  add(mText1);
  add(mText2);
 }

 public int getPreferredHeight() {
  return Display.getHeight();
 }

 public int getPreferredWidth() {
  return Display.getWidth();
 }

 protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
  width = getPreferredWidth();
  height = getPreferredHeight();

  int fieldWidth = mText1.getPreferredWidth();
  int fieldHeight = mText1.getPreferredHeight();
  layoutChild(mText1, fieldWidth, fieldHeight);
  int xPos = (width - fieldWidth) >> 1;
  int yPos = 0;
  setPositionChild(mText1, xPos, yPos);

  fieldWidth = mText2.getPreferredWidth();
  fieldHeight = mText2.getPreferredHeight();
  layoutChild(mText2, fieldWidth, fieldHeight);
  xPos = (width - fieldWidth) >> 1;
  yPos = height - fieldHeight;
  setPositionChild(mText2, xPos, yPos);
  setExtent(width, height);
 }
}
```

Sample of use:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
 CustomVerticalManager mManager = new CustomVerticalManager();

 public Scr() {
  add(mManager);
 }
}
```

See also
[Wireless - How to : Create a custom layout manager for a screen](http://blackberry-digger.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-create-custom-layout-manager-for.html)
[Blackberry - fields layout animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497073/blackberry-fields-layout-animation)

Comment: Good answer.  RIM actually had a new class in the 5.0 API called AbsoluteFieldManager but for some reason removed it from the latest beta version.