# Overlapping a UI field with another UI field in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In my project I need to put a LabelField on top of a BitmapField. I have the BitmapField inside a VerticalFieldManager. I want complete code for this problem.

My application is for BlackBerry OS 4.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class extends BitmapField and override method paintBitmap().

Like this:

```
public class MyBitmapField extends BitmapField {
//...       
protected void paintBitmap(Graphics g, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3,
        int arg4, Bitmap arg5, int arg6, int arg7) {            
    super.paintBitmap(g, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7);
    g.drawText("Your text", 5,5 );  
}

// ...

}
```

Also you can override **drawFocus()**, **paintBackground()** and other.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could draw text over bitmap:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, 100);

    public Scr() {
        //draw bitmap
        Graphics g = new Graphics(bmp);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 199, 99);
        g.drawLine(199, 0, 0, 99);

        //draw text
        Font f = getFont().derive(Font.PLAIN, 15);
        g.drawText("hello", 0, (bmp.getHeight() - f.getHeight()) >> 1, 
            DrawStyle.HCENTER|DrawStyle.VCENTER);
        add(new BitmapField(bmp));
    }
}
```

Other way is to implement custom layout like in [Blackberry - fields layout animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497073/blackberry-fields-layout-animation)

Answer (score 0):

Or use [a negative margin](http://docs.blackberry.com/pt-br/developers/deliverables/29251/Creating_a_negative_margin_1626523_11.jsp) (the source code is available for download at the bottom of that page):

[image]

**UPDATE:** One more link for  [NegativeMarginVerticalFieldManager](http://code.google.com/p/blackberry-douban-radio/source/browse/trunk/DoubanRadio/src/fm/douban/component/)

Comment: Here you go, used Google for you.