# Picker for date and time on a BlackBerry

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, datetimepicker

I want to use a date and time picker in a BlackBerry app.

Comment: anybody can give me a hint hows to implement it???

Answer (score 1):

Use `net.rim.device.api.ui.component.DateField`.

```
long yourInitialDatetime = System.currentTimeMillis();
DateField dateField = new DateField("Date:", yourInitialDatetime, 
    DateField.DATE_TIME);
yourScreen.add(dateField);
...
long currentlySelectedDatetime = dateField.getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, see [BlackBerry - Creating custom Date Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891105/blackberry-creating-custom-date-field)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this problem but the solution I used is the `DateTimePicker` Here's how you do it:

```
Calendar _dateCal;
SimpleDateFormat _dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
DateTimePicker _datePicker = DateTimePicker.createInstance(_dateCal, "dd-MMM-yyyy", null);

if(_datePicker.doModal())
{
    StringBuffer _dateStr = new StringBuffer();
    _dateCal = _datePicker.getDateTime();
    _dateFormat.format(_dateCal, _dateStr, null);
    _setDateButton.setLabel(_dateStr.toString());
}
```

That will prompt a spinner box for date selection to the screen