# How to set background of the default datetimepicker blackberry

Tags: blackberry

The default background color of `DateTimePicker` provided by blackberry is Black. I want to change this background color to the theme of my app, which is Light blue.

How can i achieve this? I am developing for OS 5.0 and above. Please help.

Comment: sorry dear there is no way to change default datetimepicker . you can choose custom or pop up solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know about this, you can't change the background of a datetimepicker. You cannot make a class that extends DateTimePicker and override its classes because it is an **abstract** class. So I guess u'll have to accept the background offered by RIM for this component.

If you check the API:
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/picker/DateTimePicker.html
you will see clearly that there is no Paint method or paintBackground method to override.

So for me there is no way to do that. You can use a work around method that will consist of creating a popup screen representing the object in question. Check the following two links for more help:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/overlapping-field-issue-on-9500/td-p/419200

Or

[BlackBerry - Creating custom Date Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891105/blackberry-creating-custom-date-field)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that you can change the default view, if you want to change that then u have to make some stub classes where you wil manually describe the classes and the functions, for the date event and import that. like importing a jar file.