# Blackbarry Simulator - Arabic support

Tags: blackberry

How do I get Arabic running on a BlackBerry? I've downloaded various simulators supporting different carriers and I've not seen Arabic offered as an input language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to see arabic text in your simulator.

For that you have to add a language manually on simulator. It can be done on any simulator. (I have added Herbew on my simulator). I recommend you to use JDE's simulator.

To do that you have to find out your simulator's xml file. You can find out in 
program files/ Research in motion/ `desired JDE`/ `simulator` folder. (e.g. `for 9000 you'll get 9000.xml`). It's recommended that you have a backup of that file.

Edit that xml file and add `<Application>net.rim.blackberry.lang.ar</Application>` (I guess that `ar` is the language code for arabic). Save it and reboot your sim.

Do visit [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Add-language-support-to-the-BlackBerry-Simulator/ta-p/445954) if you need any more help on that topic.

Comment: Thanks MobileDev123. It turned out to be easy enough to get Arabic enabled.

Comment: Welcome. I'm happy to help you and will be glad if you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download those marked as **EastAsia** or **East Asia**, ex
**BlackBerry® Device Simulators v4.6.0.307 (9000 EastAsia)**

Comment: Michael, thanks for getting back to me. I tried downloading the east asia packs last night and I don't see Arabic offered as far as I can see. Some of the languages don't have an english description next to them to it's hard to tell what's available.

Comment: you can write some test application with Arabic resources to be sure, example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928888/blackberry-unicode-text-display

Comment: After downloading the East Asia app, I noticed in the install folder that there was a set of files ending in ar for arabic, on inspection of the Device properties, I seen most languages configured except Arabic. It's almost as if the feature is there, but it's not enabled by default.