# use text entred at EditField in xml parse

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-editfield

i have two classes, one named  **Main**  other is  **Results** 


**(a) the Main class screen have 2 fields:**

1- EditField

2- ButtonField

**(b) Result class: in this class there is url connection**

i want once i click on the ButtonField it go to the other screen with the data i entred in the EditField to parse the xml accourding to my submit text

like this :

```
http://www.test.com/search.php?q=[ i want the text in the EditField to be here ]
```

pleaase i have been trying for 2 weeks

i'm very very new at BlackBerry development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okkk you can make one constructor having parameter is of String type of the `Result`class. Get the String from `EditField` in Button Click From your `Main` class like this way

```
Strnig urlString = youreditfield.getText();//this will be in fieldChanged or any method
 you have used for pushing the Screen
```

and pass this String to that class which you are pushing from the button click like this way

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Result(urlString));
```

And yourclass constructor would be

```
Result(String yourEditfieldurl) {

   Assign this url to a variable and use it in Result class that's it 

}
```

Or you can make a `Static variable`

like this 
In main class make a varible like this

`public static String editFieldUrl;`

assign the value in ButtonField click method
`editFieldUrl = yourEditfield.getText();`

and use this variable in the other class.
I think this may help you.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation, i can't vote but i mark it as solution

Comment: BBdev, do you know anything about Arabic characters they appear like "?????????" when i type it in EditField and call the parser, i see it at MDS as "??????????" and no result return

Comment: see this link http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/arabic-language-support-for-app-dev/td-p/514583

Comment: and also see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158474/blackbarry-simulator-arabic-support

Comment: well i hope my mouse could take this, it's a new war