# How to show Malayalam characters in BlackBerry application?

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an application which needs to display Malayalam text on the screen, on a LabelField. The text is now displaying like the following

> '&#3356';'&#3375';'&#3376';'&#3390';'&#3356';"

But I want to it as the follwing

> ജയരാജ

How to do that?

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928888/blackberry-unicode-text-display

Comment: I have already check this. Arabic text is displaying but malayalam not

Comment: you try to display unicode fonts or non-unicode fonts?

Comment: i am looking to display unicode font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert this into ASCII format of any Malayalam font and set this Malayalam font as the default one for the application. I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your text to javascript escapes of the format \u0987 and then this can be shown on blackberry devices.

Comment: I have already tried this but it shows only rectangles on the screen

Comment: \u0987 this is displaying correctly on the device. Can you please tell me how can I display &#3356';'&#3375';'&#3376';'&#3390';'&#3356';"

Answer (score 1):

[Check unicode converter](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/)

Paste your string in above website in mixed input and see the java script escapes and you need to convert corresponding string to unicode using String.replace i think..

Comment: No this produce rectangle on the screen