# How to implement this element for Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

I need to implement this element. [alt text http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/8107/84403853.png](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/8107/84403853.png)
It looks like main menu with different options. It should appear in the top right corner upon a click on the button with three dots (...).

Is there a native component for this for Blackberry OS 4.7.0? If not any ideas how to do it?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's context menu? try to override [Field.getContextMenu()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#getContextMenu()) and add required MenuItem instances.
Also you can try implement it with custom menu: [BlackBerry - How to create sub menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160745/blackberry-how-to-create-sub-menu)