# Styling a BlackBerry Application to Look Like an iPhone

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, custom-controls

I am porting an application from iPhone to BlackBerry. BlackBerry apps tend not to look as polished as iPhone, but naturally, I would like to maintain as much polish as I can, without breaking any important UI conventions. Are there any UI components that can help with this?

NB. I am planning to follow all important UI conventions. For example, I will use the BlackBerry Menu instead of a tab bar for providing access to help and some other advanced options.

**Links**

- [Make BlackBerry UI Components Look Like iPhone Components](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Make-Blackberry-Ui-Components-look-like-Iphone-Components/m-p/332595)

Comment: Naturally? This seems the opposite of what most developers would want to do. Ideally, any application will conform to the UI conventions of the platform it is running on.

Comment: @jball BlackBerry apps just don't look as good as iPhone. But I will avoid making it confusing for BlackBerry users

Comment: You're also going to have some fundamental problems in porting over the UI to non-touchscreen BlackBerries, which at this point are the majority of devices out there.  Touch interfaces are quite a bit different than trackball interfaces.

Comment: @Marc: My app is extremely simple and I'd have that trouble trying to build a BlackBerry app to support touchscreen/non-touchscreen anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extend [blackberry controls](http://devsushi.com/2007/12/02/blackberry-jde-api-user-interface-field-reference/) with [custom drawing](http://www.blackberry-digger.com/2009/03/code-listfield-with-check-boxes.html), or implement own one [extending Field class](http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/167). Also you may [draw a bitmap background (skin) for each control state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445953/blackberry-user-interface-design-customizable-ui/1450719#1450719).

See also
**UPDATE** [How to – Implement advanced buttons, fields and managers](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800608/How_to_-_Implement_advanced_buttons,_fields,_and_managers.html?nodeid=2406256&vernum=0)
[naviina - iPhone-style Field for Blackberry](http://www.naviina.eu/wp/blackberry/iphone-style-field-for-blackberry/)
[SO - Blackberry User Interface Design - Customizable UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445953/blackberry-user-interface-design-customizable-ui)

Answer (score 5):

This is one of those instances where providing the answer to the question you have asked is tantamount to helping commit a crime!

That sounds dramatic but as developers we have a responsibility to provide the user with a good experience - this means an experience that conforms to their expectations and makes it easy for  them to **Get Things Done**!

I know how pissed off I get when developers implemented custom interfaces in desktop applications and there I have an entire keyboard and mouse to help me navigate!

If all I have is a touchscreen or a tiny trackball and buttons then I am going to be even more pissed off.

Unless you are revolutionising user input and design on Blackberry devices - which, no offence, I doubt you are - then stick to the conventions and guidelines for that platform.

Make your software easy to use and easy to learn - do not ask a user to relearn their own platform to use your app!

Comment: I agree - it always throws me for a loop when I use Opera beta 5 on my BlackBerry Storm and they use the iPhone convention of "touch = click" rather than the Storm's "touch = focus, touch+press = click".

Comment: @Marc - I want it to look like an iPhone app - not change UI conventions like that.