# Blackberry Storm - focus issue on bitmap field

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, java-me, custom-controls, blackberry-storm

in my screen there are 3 managers
h1
h2
bmpf = new BitmapField

added in order like this as

```
backgroundmanager.add(h1)
backgroundmanager.add(bmpf)
backgroundmanager.add(h2)

add(background manager);

protected boolesn navigationClick()
{
int index1 = h1.getFieldWithFocusIndex();
int index2 = h2.getFieldWithFocusIndex();
return true;
}
```

mow i get the focus index of all focussable fields in managers h1 and h2

but i cant get index of the bitnmapfield on focus
i need to execute some code on its click

what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i set the extent of the bitmap field and placed the bitmap field in an horizontal field manager and it worked

in

```
class myscreen extends MainScreen
 {
    BitmapField mBitmapField;

    hm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
    hm.add(mBitmapField)

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
   {       
        if (hm.getFieldWithFocusIndex==0) 
        {
             Dialog.inform("Image focussed");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

i dont understand why earlier same logic was not working!!!!!!!!!!

may be bcoz of extent of BitmapField

Answer (score 1):

What for you need BitmapField index? 
Maybe it will be easier to declare BitmapField as a screen member?
If you still will need index, call [getIndex()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#getIndex%28%29) from field.

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    BitmapField mBitmapField;

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        int bmpIndex = mBitmapField.getManager.getFocusedIndex();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** Other useful method in Field class is [getManager()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#getManager%28%29):

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    BitmapField mBitmapField;

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        int index = -1;
        Manager manager = mBitmapField.getManager();
        if (manager != null) {
             index = manager.getFieldWithFocusIndex();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey i want to find the index of Bitmapfieldfield when it is focussed
i.e. focus index coz on navigation click i check the focus index n accordingly fire a code

Comment: Max it always shows index = (-1)

i also tried wid custom field but same  (-1)

Comment: why don't you simply test mBitmapField.isFocus()?

Comment: Have you created this BitmapField with FOCUSABLE style?

Comment: well i m working with storm
mBitmapField.isFocus() does not also work

n bitmapfield is also focussable

what to do

Comment: what about implement BitmapButtonField? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445953/blackberry-user-interface-design-customizable-ui/1450719#1450719

Answer (score 0):

Try to override inline the bitmapField navigationClick and drawFocus method so you dont need to care about the index, when the user click to the bitmap then your code will run.

```
protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on){
    //the simplies way to draw a rectangle and this will be the focus

}
```

protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
{
    //write here your code what you want to run the user clicks to the bitmap
    return true;
}