# Toolbar or iconbar in BlackBerry application

Tags: blackberry

I am implementing an application for BlackBerry 9300, 9700 and storm. In this application I need to create a global toolbar or iconbar similar to the Facebook application.  Please suggest how I can create this type of icon bar or tool bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [tabbed view screens](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800508/How_To_-_Create_tabbed_view_screens.html?nodeid=1357482&vernum=0)

or you can use [BlackBerry - Custom menu toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656169/blackberry-custom-menu-toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ToolbarManager to implement toolbar in blackberry,i can give u a little Example:

```
Bitmap _bit = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("abc.png");
Image _bitI = ImageFactory.createImage(_bit);
ToolbarManager _tool = new ToolbarManager();
ToolbarButtonField _next = new ToolbarButtonField(_bitI,new StringProvider("Next"));
_tool.add(_next);
this.add(_tool)

_next.setCommand(new Command(new CommandHandler(){

  public void execute(ReadOnlyCommandMetadata metadata, Object context){
   \\Do what you want on click of this ToolbarButtonField
}
}));
```

you can create as many ToolbarButtonFields as u want , just what u need to do is add those ToolbarButtonFields to ToolbarManager.

Comment: Be aware that ToolbarManager is only available in OS6 and above.