# Adding menu entries to Blackberry menu list

Tags: java, blackberry, menu, callback, dialog

Blackberry applications have a "menu" list coming up when you hit the Blackberry menu button. (When you inherit from "`MainScreen`".) But in my application there is only one entry, "Close".

How do I add entries to this menu?

<sup>(This is not a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656169/blackberry-custom-menu-toolbar), which is about replacing the standard menu with an entirely custom menu.)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a menu item using the [net.rim.device.api.ui.MenuItem](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/MenuItem.html). You can add it to a MainScreen with the [addMenuItem(MenuItem item)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html#addMenuItem%28net.rim.device.api.ui.MenuItem%29) function.

EDIT

sample code

```
MenuItem mi=new MenuItem("mymenuitem",1,1);
addMenuItem(mi);
```

Comment: Cool thanks!  Will accept as soon as I have tested on the phone, upvoted for now.

Comment: Just found the knowledge base entry from RIM itself: http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800367/How_To_-_Add_a_custom_menu_item_to_an_existing_BlackBerry_application.html?nodeid=800633&vernum=0

Comment: Actually that example from the knowledge base seems to be something different and more complicated.

Comment: The knowledge base article you link to is how to add menu items to existing BlackBerry applications (Messages, Contact List, etc). Not what you're looking for, but a good technique to know about none the less.

Comment: You're totally right. I think it's a good start anyway (you'll just have to add the MenuItem to your screen instead of the ApplicationMenuItemRepository)