# How to show field details which field is on center position?

Tags: blackberry

I have a set of fields on a horizontal scroll bar. My questions are:

1. When I scroll the fields and display the details in another layout. Which field is on center position?
2. How to move a field at center position when I click the field?

Please help me. Any ideas, links or sample code are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like CentricHManager described here

[BlackBerry - Custom centered cyclic HorizontalFieldManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550561/blackberry-custom-centered-cyclic-horizontalfieldmanager)

Also take a look at How to - Implement advanced buttons, fields, and managers on BB site

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800608/How_to_-_Implement_advanced_buttons,_fields,_and_managers.html?nodeid=2406256&vernum=0

Samples are included