# BlackBerry - How to set image as a background for ButtonField?

Tags: user-interface, image, blackberry, button

How to set image as a background for ButtonField in BlackBerry?

Answer (score 8):

Other way is to extend [ButtonField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html) and draw image on paint:

```
class BitmapButtonField extends ButtonField {
    Bitmap mNormal;
    Bitmap mFocused;
    Bitmap mActive;

    int mWidth;
    int mHeight;

    public BitmapButtonField(Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused, 
        Bitmap active) {
        super(CONSUME_CLICK);
        mNormal = normal;
        mFocused = focused;
        mActive = active;
        mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
        mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
        setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
        setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        setBorder(BorderFactory
                        .createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE, BorderFactory
                        .createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        switch (getVisualState()) {
        case VISUAL_STATE_NORMAL:
                bitmap = mNormal;
                break;
        case VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS:
                bitmap = mFocused;
                break;
        case VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE:
                bitmap = mActive;
                break;
        default:
                bitmap = mNormal;
        }
        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                        bitmap, 0, 0);
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return mWidth;
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return mHeight;
    }

    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        setExtent(mWidth, mHeight);
    }
}
```

[sample of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445953/blackberry-user-interface-design-customizable-ui/1450719#1450719)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can set an image to the [ButtonField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html). Instead, you can extend the [BitmapField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BitmapField.html) class, override the [trackwheelClick](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#trackwheelClick(int,%20int)) function and use the [onFocus](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#isFocus()) to determine if it was this field that was clicked. This will give an image that is "clickable".