# Mobile Application technologies information

Tags: iphone, android, architecture, mobile

I am new to mobile application technologies....
We are developing applications for iPhone/android/blackberry/windows mobile.

I need any PPTs of any PDF books that explain our team about
a General mobile application architecture, trends etc..

Do any one have any reference..
Please help me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android, you can refer my this answer, here you get all the STUFFs regarding Android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211193/how-to-learn-developing-android-applications/3211803#3211803

And yes, you may also refer this Website lists related to Android STUFFs...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405695/importantuseful-websites-for-the-android-related-stuff

Answer (score 0):

The answer of this question could be very big but below are few stackoverflow questions which a developer can always refer to start development on different mobile platform.

For iPhone - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c/3820926#3820926

For Blackberry - [Blackberry User Interface Design - Customizable UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445953/blackberry-user-interface-design-customizable-ui)

For Android - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405695/importantuseful-websites-for-the-android-related-stuff

Answer (score 0):

Programming the mobile web » from oreilly is really good book.