# us phone number format in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, format, phone-number

I am using a BasicEditfield.Filter_phone field...in my app.
and taking maximum 10 char in it ....but i want to enter the numbers in this field...in
(`###-###-####`) format...

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any US format only phone number fields. Why not create your own component to store the data?

This could be made up of three text fields with label fields in between them to represent the dashes.

Check out

[Blackberry User Interface Design - Customizable UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445953/blackberry-user-interface-design-customizable-ui)

for lots of links about creating a custom UI component.