# Applying themes to blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

I have developed a simple blackberry app,i need to change it look and feel,can anyone tell me how to do this ? How to apply a theme to the application .My application is a calendar application which has a drop down and few label fields,how can i apply the theme to it ?

Comment: i did not get you,i just want to apply some theme for the app

Comment: i am new to blackberry could not find much about it

Comment: I think you should edit your question and describe in more details what you are trying to achieve. IMHO, "need to change it look and feel" is too general.

Comment: i have modified it,can you please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Please check once you can get more

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Is-there-any-way-of-setting-a-theme-programmatically/m-p/192623?query.id=376348#M25966

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Blackberry User Interface Design - Customizable UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445953/blackberry-user-interface-design-customizable-ui) question and its answers, especially the one from Max Gontar (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1446712/396949). It will help you to get started.