# Blackberry UI building tool

Tags: blackberry, user-interface

I was searching for any UI building tool for BlackBerry but did not find any.
Is there any such tool so I can make my application UI fast and better?

Comment: Ths link might get you something

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445953/blackberry-user-interface-design-customizable-ui

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about developing for BlackBerry with Java ME, then no there isn't a UI building tool.

Comment: Is there any other tool to create UI of blackberry ??